# Where to write command for saving the entries of the registration form in Servlet project?

Tags: java, servlets

I want to store the information from the registration form in the database after checking the information n the controller. I also want to hash the password before saving in db. So where should I write the code for hashing of password and connection to db and its command? 
Should i write in the controller part of the registration servlet or in the view part of the success page?

Comment: A view is used to generate HTML. Why would you hash a password before writing stuff to a database in a view?

Comment: So hashing a password is to be done on the controller and then save to the db. am i right?